# Limit of a function with absolute value $(|x |+ |x-1 |- |x+1 |) ∕ x^2$

Tags: calculus

> Consider
>   $$
> f(x)=\frac{|x|+|x-1|-|x+1|}{x^2}
> $$
>   Calculate the limit of the function $f$  when $x$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Hint: in a neighborhood of $0$, you can say that $|x-1|=1-x$ and $|x+1|=x+1$, so the function is $f(x)=\frac{|x|-2x}{x^2}$

Comment: you have to consider 0+ and 0−

Comment: @JalalEddine Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

By definition of absolute value for $x\to 0$

- $x-1<0 \implies |x-1|=-(x-1)$
- $x+1>0 \implies |x+1|=x+1$

then

$$f(x)=\frac{|x|+|x-1|-|x+1|}{x^2}=\frac{|x|-(x-1)-(x+1)}{x^2}=\frac{|x|-2x}{x^2}=\frac{\frac{|x|}{x}-2}{x}$$

then consider $x\to 0^+$ and $x\to 0^-$.

Comment: thank you I managed to solve it :)

Comment: @JalalEddine Have you find out the solution?

Comment: I am stuck in the sign of |x-1| in a neighborhood of 0+

Comment: For $x\approx 0$ we have that  $x-1$ is negative then $|x-1|=-(x-1)$, can you see that?

Comment: but if we say that x\to 0^+ then x-1>-1 but we can not say that x-1 is positive because we don't know whether its between -1 and 0 or above 0

Comment: @JalalEddine let consider only the equality now for x small "x-1" is a negative number thus |x-1|=-(x-1) (try with x=-1/3 and x=1/3 for example), is it clear?

Comment: @JalalEddine I didn't understand which point is not completely clear to you.

Comment: @JalalEddine Can you get as we arrive to $f(x)=\frac{\frac{|x|}{x}-2}{x}$?

Comment: @JalalEddine Please do not hesitate to ask for any clarification!

Comment: thank you,  now I get it so when x tends to 0 that means basically its smaller than 1 right

Comment: @JalaiEddine Yes exactly! You got it, now you can consider the limit.